# VBA Is Skipping Named Range Lines

Tags: vba, excel, named-ranges

I have some code that copies data from one master file to another and then deletes the named ranges and recreates them based on the master file (couldn't find a better way to do this). The problem is, if I run the code once, the data copies and all named ranges are ONLY deleted. If I run it a second time, the named ranges are created. Any ideas why it is doing this?

```
Sub RateCardUpdate()

Dim RCWkbk As Workbook

On Error Resume Next

Set RCWkbk = Workbooks("ICARUS - Rate Card.xlsb")
If Err Then MsgBox "Please download the latest Rate Card file and open it in order to update this Rate Card."
If Err Then Exit Sub

Application.EnableCancelKey = xlDisable
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim UserWkbk As Workbook
Set UserWkbk = ThisWorkbook
Dim NR As Name

UserWkbk.Activate

    UserWkbk.Unprotect Password:="8910"
    UserWkbk.Worksheets("rc_data").Visible = True
    UserWkbk.Worksheets("rc_data").Unprotect Password:="8910"
    UserWkbk.Worksheets("drop_downs").Visible = True
    UserWkbk.Worksheets("drop_downs").Unprotect Password:="8910"

RCWkbk.Activate

    RCWkbk.Unprotect Password:="8910"
    RCWkbk.Worksheets("rc_data").Visible = True
    RCWkbk.Worksheets("rc_data").Unprotect Password:="8910"
    RCWkbk.Worksheets("drop_downs").Visible = True
    RCWkbk.Worksheets("drop_downs").Unprotect Password:="8910"

    RCWkbk.Worksheets("rc_data").Activate
    RCWkbk.Worksheets("rc_data").UsedRange.Select
    Selection.Copy

UserWkbk.Activate

    UserWkbk.Worksheets("rc_data").Activate
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats, Operation:= _
        xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

RCWkbk.Activate

    RCWkbk.Worksheets("drop_downs").Activate
    RCWkbk.Worksheets("drop_downs").UsedRange.Select
    Selection.Copy

UserWkbk.Activate

    UserWkbk.Worksheets("drop_downs").Activate
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    For Each NR In RCWkbk.Names
        UserWkbk.Names(NR.Name).Delete
        UserWkbk.Names.Add Name:=NR.Name, RefersTo:=NR.Value
    Next NR

RCWkbk.Activate

    RCWkbk.Worksheets("rc_data").Protect Password:="8910"
    RCWkbk.Worksheets("rc_data").Visible = False
    RCWkbk.Worksheets("drop_downs").Protect Password:="8910"
    RCWkbk.Worksheets("drop_downs").Visible = False
    RCWkbk.Protect Password:="8910"
    RCWkbk.Close

UserWkbk.Activate

    UserWkbk.Worksheets("rc_data").Protect Password:="8910"
    UserWkbk.Worksheets("rc_data").Visible = False
    UserWkbk.Worksheets("drop_downs").Protect Password:="8910"
    UserWkbk.Worksheets("drop_downs").Visible = False
    UserWkbk.Protect Password:="8910"

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableCancelKey = xlEnable

MsgBox "The Rate Card has been updated."

End Sub
```

That is all of the code. The section in question is:

```
  For Each NR In RCWkbk.Names
        UserWkbk.Names(NR.Name).Delete
        UserWkbk.Names.Add Name:=NR.Name, RefersTo:=NR.Value
  Next NR
```

Comment: Start by commenting out `On Error Resume Next` and rerun it.

Comment: If you delete something, how do you use its name and value in the very next line? Store the name and value in vars before deletion if you plan to reuse them.

Comment: Agree, you delete the named range and then try to refer to it where it is now nothing. Follow @Jeeped comment.

Comment: Also, for better code, don't make those `.Activate` and `Select` calls. They are mostly unnecessary and slow.  Instead you just use the worksheet references and ranges to copy and paste from and to.

Comment: If I remove On Error Resume Next it errors out trying to delete some _xlfn named ranges.

Comment: The named ranges exist in the master workbook, I'm attempting to loop through the NR's in the RCWkbk (master workbook) to duplicate them into the UserWkbk

Answer (score 0):

Like the comment from Jeeped, assign the Named Range data on some variables before you delete the Name Range so you can use them after you delete it.

```
Dim NameRangeData As String, NameRangeName As String
For Each NR In RCWkbk.Names
    NameRangeName = NR.Name
    NameRangeData = NR.Value
    UserWkbk.Names(NR.Name).Delete
    UserWkbk.Names.Add Name:=NameRangeName, RefersTo:=NameRangeData
Next NR
```

Comment: I see what you and Jeeped mean, that makes sense, but it still only deletes all NRs when I run it the first time and creates them all the second time I run it

Comment: If it makes a difference, the named ranges refer to tables

Comment: It does, a table is not exactly a named range. When you run it the second time it is creating the named range but not as a table.

Comment: Let me clarify further. There are tables being copied from the master wkbk to the user wkbk. Those tables also have named ranges associated to them as well if that makes sense. There is a list of tables as well as named ranges that refer to the tables. They are being used to create dynamic drop down lists.

Comment: It seems that when the data and tables are copied from the drop down sheet from the master to the user wkbk, the NRs in the User wkbk references break to #REF errors. The code then goes through and deletes the NR from the user wkbk as instructed but it does not subsequently re-create it. Would breaking it into 2 different loops make a difference?

Comment: Try skipping the delete and just create them.

Comment: I did try that a while back and was running into issues with that, I think it conflicted with the already existing names ranges. Interestingly enough, I cleaned up the code as GisMofx suggested and removed the .Activate's and .Select's and it seems to be working now. Not sure why but I will update if it doesn't continue to do so.